# How to provide a DNS entry with hostednetwork?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, netsh

I want to provide an AP for a mobile device via my Windows 8 Wi-Fi NIC

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=hello key=hellohello
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

does the trick but the mobile device receives the IP of the Windows 8 machine as the `DNS`.

How can I set which `DNS`es are provided via the `DHCP` of the shared connection?

Comment: I have the same question for windows 7, because DNS is not working when i connect to my hostes network